# Двумерный массив JAVA

Tags: java

Как в java произвести такое, только в двумерном массиве?

```
for (int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {
        x[i] = x[i-1];
        y[i] = y[i-1];
    }
```

dots = 3;

Comment: Какое такое? Непонятна суть вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Написать двойной цикл

```
for(int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {
  for(int j=0; j < x[0].length; j++){
    x[i][j] = x[i-1][j];
  }
}
```